# Easiest way to sort JSON.parse list in jQuery

Tags: jquery, sorting

I have a list like this one (it is already proper sorted in php)

```
myList = {  
   "394":"Andres",
   "388":"Franck",
   "380":"John",
   "415":"Philip"
}
```

But if I use `data = JSON.parse(myList)` to make an object for dropdown, as respons I am getting list automatically sorted by keys what actually I do not want.

Result:

```
data = {
   "380":"John",
   "388":"Franck",
   "394":"Andres",
   "415":"Philip"
}
```

So what is the best way to make sort on list as JSON object to get list sorted by values?

I have tried:

```
var keyList = Object.keys(data).sort(function(a,b){return data[a]-data[b]});
   var valueLIst = Object.values(data).sort(function(a,b){return data[a]-data[b]});

   var obj = {};
   for(var i=0,len=keyList.length; i < len ;i++) {
     obj[keyList[i]] = valueLIst[i];
   }
```

Comment: The order of keys in objects is not guaranteed. Do not rely on it. Use array instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally your PHP API should be returning an array, because JavaScript objects are an [unordered collection of properties](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) by definition.

> #### 4.3.3 Object
>
> An object is a member of the
> type Object. **It is an unordered collection of properties** each of which
> contains a primitive value, object, or
> function. A function stored in a
> property of an object is called a
> method.

However, you could transform the API response into an ordered array of objects, if you want to keep the PHP response how it is now:

```
Object.keys(data).map(key => ({ id: key, value: data[key] }))
                 .sort((a, b) => a.value.localeCompare(b.value));
```

Interestingly you could also use `Map` which orders based on insertion order.